# Connect to Service after activity recreation

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

I have Activity and Service which plays music. onCreate of activity I startService and trying to create a ServiceConnection, in ServiceConnection's onServiceConnected I initialize service, so after this it is not null. Then I bindService to this serviceConnection.

So, my musicService is not null, application works, service can send foreground notifications. Let's say I rotated my device and screen rotated, my activity calls onDestroy and calls onCreate. My musicService continues playing, but in onCreate there is startService, creation of ServiceConnection and bindService again, application crashes because of null musicService.

I revealed that it is because of ServiceConnection's onServiceConnected is never called now.
What should I do to connect to my created on first activity start musicService?

My code which runs on every onCreate:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicPlaybackService.class);
    startService(intent);
    serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            musicPlaybackService = binder.getService(); 
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        }
    };
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection, 0);
```

Comment: Add code. Will make the situation much easier

Comment: Done, but I'm not sure that it makes something easier, I think my description is pretty full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what i did but it works. Now I have this code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicPlaybackService.class);
    MyApplication.getAppContext().startService(intent);
    serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            musicPlaybackService = binder.getService();
            // now onServiceConnected calls on screen rotation.
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        }
    };
    MyApplication.getAppContext().bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```